# Angular reuse of property from component to component

Tags: angular, components, angular5

I'm starting in Angular, did the tutorial, tried to grasp concepts but I'm stuck with what seems to be a simple problem. Tried to google around, but I couldn't get this resolved.

In Angular 5, how would you re-use a property (here title) from component to component? 
Let's say I have the property `title` defined in `app.component.ts` that I want in the end to reuse in `login.compoment.html`??

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule
  ],

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],

  providers:[
    // services
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector : 'app-root',
  template : `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'A global title...';
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector   : 's-login-pg',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls  : [ './login.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    // should title be referenced here? 
    // should the AppComponent be imported again, as they are already both defined in app module ?
}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div>{{title}}</div> <!-- I want the title in app.component.ts to show up -->
```

Can you please advise on how this should be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data in Angular wither via `@Input()` / `@Output()` or via a shared `Service`.

**@Inout / @Output** is recommended if you pass data from parent to child components (though you can send it deeper in the same manner).

**Service** is recommended if you pass data deeper. In your case it seems you pass it deeper. So what you do is create a new `custom-service.service.ts` file, add it to providers array in `app.module.ts` (so it becomes a Singleton for the whole app), inject this service to all components that communicates. Store a property in service - `title: string`.

In `app.component.ts` you inject this service:

```
import {CustomService} from '...path'

title = 'My title';
constructor(private custService: CustomService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.custService.title = this.title;
}
```

Now every component that imports that service, can acces it's `title` property and get it's value:

```
import {CustomService} from '...path'

title: string;
constructor(private custService: CustomService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.title = this.custService.title;
}
```